# Incorrect constant buffer size

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

I have created a following constant buffer:

```
// C++    
struct IndexConstantBuffer
{
    unsigned indexes[32]{};
};

// hlsl
cbuffer IndexConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    uint indexes[32];
};
```

I am having the following warning:

> D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexedInstanced: The size of
> the Constant Buffer at slot 0 of the Pixel Shader unit is too small
> (128 bytes provided, 512 bytes, at least, expected). This is OK, as
> out-of-bounds reads are defined to return 0. It is also possible the
> developer knows the missing data will not be used anyway. This is only
> a problem if the developer actually intended to bind a sufficiently
> large Constant Buffer for what the shader expects. [ EXECUTION WARNING
> #351: DEVICE_DRAW_CONSTANT_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL]

What causes this warning? Do I need to add a padding of 384 bytes (512 - 128) or is there another way around?

Comment: Sounds like you have your answer

Comment: In this case, you should pack 4 indices into vector, in HLSL your cbuffer would be uint4 indices[8], and in C++ your struct would look something like XMUINT4 indices[8] or whatever vector class you are using.

Comment: What is ``sizeof(IndexConstantBuffer)``?

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but let's try and provide a definitive answer.

To resolve this error you must ensure the C++ data structure exactly aligns with the HLSL data structure. The alignment rules for C++ and HLSL are NOT the same -- they are very different languages that just happen to share some similarities. Although you can force C++ alignment to behave exactly like HLSL, instances such as this will incur additional padding (consuming additional memory) without offering any benefit in performance. In this case you would be consuming 4 times the memory (512 bytes instead of the optimal 128 bytes required).

Array elements are always packed on 16-byte boundaries in HLSL while they are packed on 4-byte boundaries in C++ (by default). This is clearly inefficient when the elements are 4-byte integrals, but is optimal when dealing with **float4** elements (four component vectors) which are by far the most common datatype in HLSL. This is because the GPU can access 128-bits with a single instruction, and can thus retrieve all 4 components of a **float4** at once.

To avoid inserting unnecesary padding in your array, your C++ array needs to be mapped to an 8-element array of type **uint4** in HLSL. In other words, each element in HLSL becomes a 4-component vector of type **uint**.

In addition, you should be more precise when specifying your element types in C++. An **unsigned** type (implying an **unsigned int**) has an implementation-defined size (in **char**s). While it is 4 **char**s in most cases, you cannot guarantee it across all implementations. Even the length of a **char** cannot be guaranteed to be 8-bits. However, the C++ standard (since C++11) defines a set of fixed-width integrals and these should be preferred whenever you require an integral of specific size, such as when declaring an HLSL data structure in C++ which includes one or more integrals.

Implementing the following modifications will resolve the error:

```
// C++
#include <cstdint> // for uint32_t    
struct IndexConstantBuffer
{
    // unsigned indexes[32]{}; // Implementation-defined size
    uint32_t indexes[32]{}; // Always 128-bytes
};

// hlsl
cbuffer IndexConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    // uint indexes[32];  // (4 + 12) * 32 = 512 (bytes) incl. padding
    uint4 indexes[8]; // (4 * 4) * 8 = 128 (bytes) no padding
};
```

Of course, accessing the elements in HLSL will now require you to treat each element as a **uint4** (a vector of four **uint** elements) rather than as a single **uint**, however this is trivial to resolve in HLSL.